# Expected running time to find Randomized Median

Tags: algorithm, random

I have tried hard , but i'm unable to come up with the expected running time for the number of comparisons to find the Randomized Median(finding the median of an unsorted array in order n time). Also i wanted to make sure that we CANNOT take expectation of the recurrence that we use to find the randomized median , or any other recurrence in any other problem as they belong to different probability spaces? Is this statement right?

Comment: What's a *Randomized Mean*?

Comment: finding the median of an unsorted array

Comment: This question should be on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the algorithm, the general name of the problem is [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).  One popular algorithm is [quick select](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect), the average performance of this is linear (i.e. the number of comparisons is k*N, with k typically around 2)  but the worst case performance is bad, like O(N*N).  There are [other algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) with other trade-offs.